# How do I learn if events are bound to an element using jquery?

Tags: jquery, events

I need a `hasEvents()` method like

```
var someBool = hasEvents($("#myelement"));
```

that returns `true` if there are some bound events to any of the element's event handlers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

have you taken a look at the [`hasEvent()`](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hasevent) plugin? the code is pretty small:

```
(function(A) {
    A.fn.hasEvent = function(C) {
       var B = this.data("events");
       return( B && B[C] )
    }
}) (jQuery)
```

for your specific purpose you could modify it slightly:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasEvents = function() {
        return new Boolean(this.data('events') );
    }
}) (jQuery);

$('#someDiv').click(function() {
    alert('new event');
});

$('#someDiv').hasEvents();      // true
$('#someOtherDiv').hasEvents(); // false
```